# Smoothing directional (angular) data in R

Tags: r, rotation, motion-detection

I'm trying to deal with some `motion analysis` software tracking errors **after** the data is exported. For some frames the direction is rotated by 180 degrees from the "true" direction.

I would like to smooth the data set so that when the direction changes by ~180 in a single frame, it is transformed to reflect the actual angle.

Is anyone aware of a way to solve this using any of the circular statistics packages in `R` language such as `CircStats`? Alternatively, I could imagine a script that checks if frame to frame variation is near 180 degrees, subtracts 180 if this is true, then moves to the next frame. Does this sound like a reasonable approach and would it be easily implemented in R?

I'm afraid I don't have the rep to upload a figure describing the problem (it's very easy to see), but [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6XyvizgdJ1PamVYYlRtUUgtakU/view?usp=sharing) is a example dataset.

Thanks for the help. I've been a longtime user of stack overflow but have never failed to find my answer before needing to ask before.

David

edit - attached image
[image]

Comment: You could see the differences easily with `dat <- ts(dat); diffs <- dat - lag(dat, k = 1); hist(diffs)`. Do you have a "range of differences", or rather a simple a threshold -- like abs(diffs) > 170 -- for which you want to apply the transformation?

Comment: A threshold would work nicely. I've been using 90 in my own attempts to solve this. 
And thanks for reminding me about lag(), that will help with those pesky NAs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an interesting problem to solve! It needs to be iterative since whenever a value is changed, it can solve a problem but create another... Let me know if it does the trick.

```
threshold <- 90
correction <- 180

dat <- read.table("angle_data.txt", header=TRUE)
dat <- ts(dat)

repeat {
    diffs <- dat - lag(dat, k = 1)
    probl <- which(abs(diffs[,2]) > threshold)

    if(length(probl)==0)
        break

    obs.1 <- dat[probl[1], 2]
    obs.2 <- dat[probl[1] + 1, 2]

    dat[probl[1] + 1, 2] <- obs.2 + sign(obs.1 - obs.2) * 180
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!

That certainly solves my problem. Still working on figuring out what's going on here though.

Comment: You're welcome! Figuring why the problem occurs or what happens in the proposed solution?

Comment: The solution, but I got it now.